Kotlin Android Crashes when the OkHttp Request is created
I have created a Module for Network calls.
It works well when tested on the same Project for all API methods.
But When I add it as a dependency on another project it fails When a request is created.
return Request.Builder()
            .url(urlObj)
            .build()


FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Lokhttp3/Request$Builder;

(I am new to Android. I have only 3 days of Android and Kotlin experience )
Project Location: https://github.com/manoj86/aOS_iNetwork

can you share the project on github or something? might be easier for us to find the reason :)

@JustSightseeing I have added the repo link

So the problem is local aar would not download the dependencies defined in it when they are added to other local projects.
They are downloaded when the library is published to Maven and imported from there.
All the dependencies are to be added again to the project that included the local arr as library.

I pulled the repo and changed the response in hasConnection to a new url (as I'm not hosting anything on http://10.0.2.2:8102/test) and the thing just... runs?

I would suggest invalidating caches and syncing project with gradle files

unless you've tried to add the return Request.Builder().url(urlObj).build() to your app module ? I only found similar lines in the networking module

Thank you very much for testing this. Have you tried adding the aars to some other project and made the hasConnection call? Because that is where it fails.

yes, I just did, it works

btw, as this is a module meant for sharing between projects I would suggest adding api(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json) to the networking modules (so all modules depending on it have the serialization plugin installed)

and if you didn't use the version catalog you wouldn't require the future module users to add the dependenies themselves to their version catalog (but it also prevents them from modifying the versions of the libraries, which is a pro and a con at the same time)

"Have you tried adding the aars to some other project", I just imported a module, is that what you mean?

Not the module. aar should be added into libs folder and then referred to that location inside the dependencies in build.gradle

may you be creating a release version of the .aar?

Seems the okhttp3 dependencies cant be scanned by your new project, try editing your okhttp3 dependencies to just like this: change implementation okhttp3 to api okhttp3 on your module build gradle files.

Thanks for your reply, Ruby. I have shared the git hub link for the sample project.

not sure how that would help, api are meant to be transitively exported to other modules
